# passing bash array values to bc

Tags: arrays, bash, bc

I have a bash array of floating point numbers, say it is called `vals` and intialized like this --

```
# load data from the datafile.txt

vals=`cat datafile.txt` 
vals=($vals)
```

The `datafile.txt` looks like this --

```
0.012256791324227446
0.012424287090558156
0.013912725724889032
0.014678182257134693
```

Now I need to calculate the average of element 1 and 2 in `vals` using bc, I am doing as follows --

```
result=$(echo "(${vals[1]} + ${vals[2]})/2.0" | bc)
echo result: $result
```

but the `result` is always `0`, please note that the elements are not `0.0`.

any idea?

**EDIT : The data are changed.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually call `bc -l` if I need floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scale` to define the amount of digits after the decimal point:

```
$ echo "scale=5; (${vals[1]} + ${vals[2]})/2.0" | bc
.49580

$ echo "scale=3; (${vals[1]} + ${vals[2]})/2.0" | bc
.495
```

From [`man bc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html):

> **scale** ( expression )
>
> The value of the scale function is the number of digits after the
>   decimal point in the expression.

---

Also, note this suffices:

```
vals=$(cat datafile.txt)
```